# Is there a way to get VM details in log analytics workspace using azure powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

Im trying to fetch vitual machines inside log analytics workspace. i didnt found an exact command to get that. please let me know if u know something
Thanks in advance

Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace i tried this command
this will give accounts inside log analytics workspace. im expecting vm details for each account

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-AzVMExtension` with `MicrosoftMonitoringAgent` extension which would give the details of the log analytics workspace that it is attached to. Below is the script that worked for me to achieve your requirement.

```
$Rg = '<YourResourceGroup>'
$LogWS = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName $Rg
$VmList = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $Rg

foreach($Vm in $VmList)
{
    $AllVMsDetails = Get-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $Rg -VMName $Vm.Name -Name 'MicrosoftMonitoringAgent'
    $workspaceID=($AllVMsDetails.PublicSettings|ConvertFrom-Json).workspaceId
    if($LogWS.CustomerId -eq $workspaceID)
    {
        $AllVMsDetails
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]